# Something similar to NUnit TestCaseSource in Visual Studio unit testing

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

Is there anything similar to NUnit TestCaseSource attribute in Visual Studio unit testing?  The closest solution I found was to use a DataSource.  But I don't want to store my test case parameters in a data source.

Comment: from where you want to execute your test cases?

Comment: I would like to execute the tests from Visual Studio.  In the future we would be integrating the tests as part of the build process.

Comment: Based on my experience in Visual Studio unit testing, it's better to switch to NUnit earlier. Even there are lots of workaround for any problems, it costs too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datasource is one option to take the test input. You can save your test data in many file format (xml, xls or in sql db)

But if you don't want to store your test data, then use TestInitialize() attribute in any method that will execute before any of your test cases. Save all your test data run time in xml,xls or in sql db through this method and then using datasource use it in your test cases.

Here is [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link for VSTS unit test. Hope this will help you.