# How to run test case with data from property in MSTest?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, data-driven-tests

Is there some analogue of **NUnit** `[Test, TestCaseSource("PropertyName")]` or **xUnit** `[Theory, PropertyData("PropertyName")]` in **MSTest**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DataSource (Attribute) is what you are looking for.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625(v=vs.80).aspx
[Something similar to NUnit TestCaseSource in Visual Studio unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054025/something-similar-to-nunit-testcasesource-in-visual-studio-unit-testing)

Comment: Does DataSource provide connection to some sort of IEnumerable property?